# 12.04 Automount EXT4

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, mount, automount

I have a secondary hard drive on my computer. It has a partition that is ext4 that I set up for Ubuntu. I would like for it to be mounted automatically. I tried using the *Disk Utility* that I installed form the software center. But the version is only 3.0 and the new one that has the auto-mount feature is 3.8, which is not available to 12.04. How can U auto mount my ext4 partition that is on a secondary hard drive?

This is what the disk utility looks like.

[image: ignore the blue]